# Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#

This is the source code( I am using CodeSmith Tools):

```
public static int Delete(this System.Data.Linq.Table<EAccredidation.Data.Programs> table, int pKProgramID)
{
    return table.Delete(p => p.PKProgramID == pKProgramID);
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type   C:\Projects\New\EAccreditation.Data\Queries\ProgramsExtensions.Generated.cs

How can I fix it?

Comment: Um, did you really mean for your method to be recursive?

Comment: ...and that's the reason for the error!  @RaymondChen put it as an answer and you'll be +1d

Comment: I work for CodeSmith Tools... What is the type of p.PKProgramID? Are you getting any other build errors? Please see this for more information: http://community.codesmithtools.com/Template_Frameworks/f/66/t/10974.aspx

Comment: Hi Blake,
Thank you for your response.
I got this project 2 days ago, and unfortunately it is incomplete (is missing even the .csp file, and also using an older version of CodeSmith v 4), and I am trying to recover it, for future modification. We are trying to create a VM Server with all the software support installed on (because there are some other incompatibilities between software’s version) 
And yes, I am getting this kind of error for all Delete procedures and the field PK_ProgramId (PK, int, not null), the same for the other fields used in Delete procedures
Thanks again for your time

Comment: Since, you are going to build the development environment; I have another question for you.
CodeSmith 5 uses .Net Framework 3.5 or 4?
Thanks again

Comment: @DodoV, I work for CodeSmith... I'd recommend getting a 5.x (if you need vs2008/6.x (vs2010.. you can use multitargeting) trial and the latest version of PLINQO. They are backwards compatible with previous versions of PLINQO (minus one or two minor things which can be fixed easily). It wouldn't take very much to figure out the exact settings of the missing CSP. They are using either the Query Extensions or Manager Extensions and then you need to look at the naming conventions. You can also get the version number of the templates they used, by looking at the CodeSmith.Data assembly.

Answer (score 6):

You've stipulated your method as an extension method, so for the purposes of your example, you can ignore the first parameter on the method declaration.

Therefore, the only parameter you are concerned with is the second, `int pKProgramID`.

When you call this method (recuirsively) it expects an int, but you are passing a lambda delegate (`p => p.PKProgramID == pKProgramID`)

And, as Raymond Chen intimated in his comment, your method is recursive, so you may have further pain ahead of you!

Comment: of course, **if** there was an overload elsewhere of table.Delete(predicate), then the code would be fine

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt predicate-based delete. You would have to use:

```
table.DeleteAllOnSubmit(table.Where(p => p.PKProgramID == pKProgramID));
```

or since we assume the PK is unique:

```
var record = table.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PKProgramID == pKProgramID);
if(record != null) table.DeleteOnSubmit(record);
```

You will of course also need to `SubmitChanges()` on the context at some point.

Comment: Thank you guys,
Unfortunately, if I am ignoring the first parameter on the method declaration, I am getting: 
“The name ‘table’ does not exist in the current context”
And I really need the expression p => p.PKProgramID == pKProgramID

Any thoughts…
Thanks again

Comment: @Dobo I don't understand the comment: I didn't suggest changing the signature, and I don't understand your "And I really need..." - since I used exactly that in both examples

Comment: Delete in this case is an extension method.

Comment: @Blake since we can't see the signature of hat, it is hard for us to comment accurately

Comment: @Blake You are going to build the development environment;So, I have another question for you. CodeSmith 5 uses .Net Framework 3.5 or 4? Thanks again

Comment: @MarcGravell, it's all good, I just wanted to correct this post. Thanks for taking the time to help the poster :).

Comment: @DodoV, CodeSmith Generator 5 is compiled on the .NET 3.5 runtime (note that it just generates text so you can generate anything including .NET 1.0,4,5,..10.   CodeSmith Generator 6.x which has been released is compiled against .net 4.0

Comment: @Blake, Thanks again for your time

Regarding to your question: yes, I am getting this kind of error for all Delete procedures and the field PK_ProgramId (PK, int, not null), the same for the other fields used in Delete procedures

Comment: @Dodo, If you could contact support with a sample application that reproduces this, it would be greatly appreciated and we will get to the bottom of this.